# Должен ли я использовать has_key () или in в Python dict?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Что лучше использовать in:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
'a' in d
True
```

или has_key:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d.has_key('a')
True
```

Comment: in лаконичнее имхо

Comment: `has_key` - был удален в `3.x`, по этому, лучше использовать `in`. [Пруф](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)

Comment: Можно увидеть более развернутый ответ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать `in`, так как алгоритмическая сложность при такой проверке будет линейна.Также, судя по бенчмаркам, это наиболее быстрое решение [Пруф](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary/30527984#30527984)